# Accessing custom user profile fields in CCK

Tags: drupal-6

I'm probably going about this the wrong way but...

I’ve added a field to the User Profile called profile_real_name which is required by the user. Is there a way to access the details in CCK?

For example in CCK when creating a new field I can access the user’s username with the ‘User reference’ Field type and setting the ‘Widget type’ to ‘Autocomplete text field’. Can I do the same with my real name field?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Users are not a part of the node system and therefore fields cannot be mapped to Users using only Core code.

CCK doesn't have a way to manipulate and add fields to profile.

There is one solution to this: [nodeprofile](http://drupal.org/project/nodeprofile) (Drupal 5). This module creates a node  type for users, so each user effectively has one node that is associated with it. You can then add fields to this new content type and manipulate them how you wish.

There is also a module, [content_profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile), for Drupal 6 which does the same.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I saw the module was only availble for drupal 5x but it was still a helpful answer. Thank you:)